# Python class is defined, everything is defined but I can't figure out a print method to print it all out

Tags: python

It's set up in a class function with variables like this.

```
Season_1 = AHS('yada', 'yada', 'yada')
Season_2 = AHS('yada', 'yada', 'yada')
Etc... Through 9 seasons.
```

What I can't figure out is how to set up a print method to print all of them out instead of

```
Print(season_1.yada)
Print(season_2.yada)
```

What can I do to make it simpler?
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RNC.jpg) here is a link for better context. I'm a python and stack noob sorry for that :/

Comment: Any time you feel the need to append special labels to your variables like `_1`, `_2`, etc., that is an indicator that you should be using a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: If you have multiple values, **don't** do `name_1` etc, just use the list!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a function that takes a list of seasons:

```
def print_yada(seasons):
    for s in seasons:
        print(s.yada)

print_yada([season_1, season_2])
```

As mentioned in the comments, start with a list rather than a bunch of numbered variable names.

```
seasons = [
    AHS('yada', 'yada', 'yada'),
    AHS('yada', 'yada', 'yada'),
    AHS('yada', 'yada', 'yada')
]
print_yada(seasons)
```

There won't be a single `AHS` method that can do this, because you aren't dealing with a single *instance* of `AHS`, but rather a collection of them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, if it isn't obvious I'm very new and realize stack is much better for these kinda questions than Reddit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting your seasons in a list, instead of individual variables

```
seasons = [AHS('foo'), AHS('bar'), ...]
```

Then you can loop through them

```
for season in seasons:
    print(season.yada)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you probably require an actual list, persumably within your class, if it provides any functionality on the members above what built-in Python collections already do. If not, you don't need a class.

If, on the other hand, "yada", "yada", "yada" are actually fixed members that define what your class is, and you are basically looking for a way to print an object of such a class, you can define the  `__str__` member method of your class to create a readable output format for your objects, persumably referring to their members.

`__str__()` should return a string that is used when an object of your class is converted to one, such as when printing.
It has no parameters aside from the mandatory instance parameter.
E.g.:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = (a, b)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"My members are: {self.a}, {self.b}"

print(MyClass(3, "abc"))
```

> My members are: 3, abc